# Python: create a function calling a class attribute

Tags: python, function, class

I have the following script:

```
 #we create a class for a product and its description

class Producto:
    def __init__(self, id_producto, linea_produccion, eval_numerica, eval_visual):
        self.id_producto = id_producto
        self.linea_produccion = linea_produccion
        self.eval_numerica = eval_numerica
        self.eval_visual = eval_visual



#here I enter product´s description
def lee_producto():
    id_producto = input()
    linea_produccion = input()
    eval_numerica = (float(input()))
    verificacion = input()
    eval_visual = ( verificacion == "s" )
    return Producto(id_producto, linea_produccion, eval_numerica, eval_visual)

#We call the previous function and add products
def lee_y_anade_producto(lista):
    nuevo_producto = lee_producto()
    lista.append(nuevo_producto)

#we call the previous function as many times as n
lista = []
n = int(input("cuantos productos vas a dar de alta:   ")) 
for i in range(n):
    lee_y_anade_producto(lista)
```

So far all that I have done is to feed information to my Class object, I don´t know how to do it backward, now that I have the information the way I want it How can I access to it, depending on the piece of information I want?

1. Show all products in a line (that's `self.linea_produccion a1, b2,c3`) and show all items depending on what line I choose (`a1, b2, c3`)

.
 2. And I need to calculate `self.eval_numeric` average of all items,
    regardless of everything else.

This is for learning purposes, I really want to understand how to and not just copy-paste.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, can you explain things differently, perhaps?

Comment: @AMC I know how to input data to a class object, now I need to extract that data

Comment: You just didn't know how to access the attributes of an object, is that all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have `lista` which is a list of your `Producto` objects. This is what you have:

```
lista = []
n = int(input("cuantos productos vas a dar de alta:   ")) 
for i in range(n):
    lee_y_anade_producto(lista)
```

After this you can iterate through the list and get the attributes of each object like this:

```
for object in lista:
    id_producto = object.id_producto
    linea_produccion = object.linea_produccion
```

Anything that is set as `self.attribute` in `__init__` can be called by `object.attribute`.

Comment: But here I´m creating a list, using lista=[], and that list stores n products does that list keeps the same structure as the class object?

Comment: @RenéMartínez I've edited to answer your comment. Please try my suggestion and let me know if it works.

Comment: it did work, but I have anoter question, Why does print(lista.id_producto) gives error? shouldn´t that print all list´s id_producto?

Comment: @RenéMartínez `lista` is a list of objects so it does not have the attribute `id_producto`. You can access an individual object inside the list with an index, like this: `lista[0].id_producto`